# Use of label in sqlalchemy , database, ORM

Tags: python, database, python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy

```
q = session.query(
    label('id1', func.least(Communication.initiator_id, Communication.receiver_id)),
    label('id2', func.greatest(Communication.initiator_id, Communication.receiver_id)),
    label('orga_id1', func.greatest(0, 1)),
    label('orga_id2', func.greatest(0, 1)),
    label('nb', func.count(Communication.id))
).filter(
    or_(
        Communication.initiator_id == people_id,
        Communication.receiver_id == people_id
    )
).order_by("nb").group_by('id1', 'id2').all()
```

So i have this piece of code, and it's working fine but only one thing i would like to add here, and that thing is the use of labels.
For Exemple how do i use the name label "id1" in my other label?

I my code to be something like this:

```
q = session.query(
    label('id1', func.least(Communication.initiator_id, Communication.receiver_id)),
    label('id2', func.greatest(Communication.initiator_id, Communication.receiver_id)),
    label('orga_id1', func.greatest(session.query(People).filter_by(id = "And here somehow i want the value that was created on first label with name 'id1'").first().orga_id, -1)),
    label('orga_id2', func.greatest(session.query(People).filter_by(id = "And here somehow i want the value that was created on second label with name 'id2'").first().orga_id, -1)),
    label('nb', func.count(Communication.id))
).filter(
    or_(
        Communication.initiator_id == people_id,
        Communication.receiver_id == people_id
    )
).order_by("nb").group_by('id1', 'id2').all()
```

Can someone pls explain me how do i use the value of labels inside the query !!!

Comment: You cannot reference a label from the select list of a parent query in a subquery the way you're trying. You can on the other hand reference the parent table, so you could use `Communication.initiator_id` etc. thanks to SQLAlchemy's [auto correlation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#correlated-subqueries). But: `Query.first()` performs the query then and there. You want to use [`Query.as_scalar()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.as_scalar), selecting `People.id`.

Comment: but for exemple , can i change the value of  `q[0].orga_id1 = "new value"` after ending the query by using my first exemple? and if yes how do i do this ? bcs if i do like `q[0].orga_id1 = 11` i get the error `can't set attribute`

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Another thing: if you filter People by *id*, select first and then use the *id* of that, why do you need the subquery at all? What I mean is that `session.query(People).filter_by(id=the_id1).first().id` would equal the id1. Is there a typo?

Comment: Edited, i am searching for organization_id that people is situated in, bcs i need the id of people and aswell the id of organization that they are working in but only by the id that is apearing in the column id1 id2 and to have 2 columns with the id of organization

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot reference the output columns of the parent query in a subquery, though you could reference the parent's source tables:

```
select 1 as one, (select one) as two;
```

will not work, but

```
select 1 as one, (select s.i) as two from generate_series(2, 2) s(i);
```

does. You can on the other hand first perform your query for fetching the communications and counts and then add the Persons' organization ids on top. Using scalar subqueries the way you've envisioned originally:

```
id1 = func.least(Communication.initiator_id, Communication.receiver_id)
id2 = func.greatest(Communication.initiator_id, Communication.receiver_id)

sq = session.query(id1.label('id1'),
                   id2.label('id2'),
                   func.count(Communication.id).label('nb')).\
    filter(or_(Communication.initiator_id == people_id,
               Communication.receiver_id == people_id)).\
    order_by('nb').\
    group_by('id1', 'id2').\
    subquery()

orga_id1 = session.query(People.orga_id).filter_by(id=sq.c.id1).as_scalar()
orga_id2 = session.query(People.orga_id).filter_by(id=sq.c.id2).as_scalar()

q = session.query(sq.c.id1,
                  sq.c.id2,
                  func.greatest(orga_id1, -1).label('orga_id1'),
                  func.greatest(orga_id2, -1).label('orga_id2'),
                  sq.c.nb).\
    all()
```

With LEFT JOINs:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import aliased

id1 = func.least(Communication.initiator_id, Communication.receiver_id)
id2 = func.greatest(Communication.initiator_id, Communication.receiver_id)

people1 = aliased(People)
people2 = aliased(People)

sq = session.query(id1.label('id1'),
                   id2.label('id2'),
                   func.count(Communication.id).label('nb')).\
    filter(or_(Communication.initiator_id == people_id,
               Communication.receiver_id == people_id)).\
    order_by('nb').\
    group_by('id1', 'id2').\
    subquery()

q = session.query(sq.c.id1,
                  sq.c.id2,
                  func.coalesce(people1.orga_id, -1).label('orga_id1'),
                  func.coalesce(people2.orga_id, -1).label('orga_id2'),
                  sq.c.nb).\
    outerjoin(people1, people1.id == sq.c.id1).\
    outerjoin(people2, people2.id == sq.c.id2).\
    all()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helped me ! :)